# Hibernate problem: "Too many connections"

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting the following error:

```
.
.
.
.
6844 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1040, SQLState: 08004
6844 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor121.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:345)
    at $Proxy0.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at com.mycomp.myproj.matcher.Matcher.findMatch(Matcher.java:228)
    at com.mycomp.myproj.Confidence.Confidence.main(Confidence.java:160)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1105)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2186)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:787)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor16.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:357)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 11 more
```

The hibernate bits of my program are like this:

```
for loop_1        // this will execute say 2000 times 
{
    for loop_2       // this will execute say 1000 times
    {
        // Opening 2 sessions for 2 different databases

        Configuration config_1 = new Configuration().configure("Hibernate_1.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory_1 = config_1.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session_1 = sessionFactory_1.getCurrentSession();
        session_1.beginTransaction();

        Configuration config_2 = new Configuration().configure("Hibernate_2.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory_2 = config_2.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session_2 = sessionFactory_2.getCurrentSession();
        session_2.beginTransaction();

        doInsertDb_1(some_object_1, session_1);

        doUpdateDb_2(some_object_2, session_2);
    }
}

    public int doInsertDb_1(Object obj, Session session) {

        try {

            session.save(obj);
            session.flush();
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            return 1;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public int doUpdate_2(Object obj, Session session) {

        try {

            Query query = session.createQuery("" <Creating some query> );
            query.executeUpdate();
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            return 1;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

It is obvious that somewhere I am not closing the connections properly. I am not able to figure out where? Can someone please guide me with this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you need to create both sessions each time through the loop? Creating them once, prior to both loops, would likely solve your problem and speed-up your code. If you insist on opening them in the inner loop, though, make sure to `close()` them afterwards, since that should at least free up the database connections you're opening (but never closing.)

**EDIT**: You should hold off on committing your changes until you've made them all, so that you won't prematurely close the connections.

**EDIT 2**: Since you need the results of each update for processing further updates, you can at least move the creation of the SessionFactories outside the loops.

Comment: @dlev: Thanks for your reply. as i replied to Cris, if i create them outside `for loop_1`, i get `Session already closed!` error. This is because when I do `session.getTransaction().commit();`, I can see in the debugger that it closes the session after this stmt.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps you should just hold off on committing until you've made all your changes?

Comment: i will surely try that. somewhere i found that closing Statement and ResultSet helped the asker. I am also doing some selects in each loop (which i did not add in my question). so thought thats the problem. but i am closing the Statement and ResultSet as well, and still the same problem.

Comment: @dlev: your suggestion helps but there is one problem. in the loop, when i insert records in the db, i have to consider that record in the next loop. so if i don't commit it immediately, i am not able to get that record and hence the final output is wrong. is there any better way?

Comment: Hmm... one possibility would be move the SessionFactory creation outside both loops, but keep the Session creation itself inside. Does that work?

Answer (score 2):

Try to create sessions outside the loop

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to create them outside of `for loop_2` and I got the same error. Also, I tried to create them outside of `for loop_2` and I am getting `Session already closed!`, which is expected.

Comment: i created the session outside the loop and also removed the `session.getTransaction().commit();` stmt, and i am now committing the transaction outside `for loop_1`. but when i insert records in the db, i have to consider that record in the next loop. so if i don't commit it immediately, i am not able to get that record and hence the final output is wrong. is there any better way?